# Adding functionality to a product

Tags: twitter, product, saas

I have an SAAS online product (it affects people with twitter accounts, suggests people\pages to follow based on your previous interests).

I would like to add the option to schedule tweets (an ability to not send a tweet now, but schedule it for later, so a person can schedule several tweets at a time and it will be send out during the week) to my product, because I have noticed a lot of people pay for it.

How can I add this functionality to my product, in a way that will be competitive and people will use it?

I would greatly appreciate any help with this, since it's a key for my product's growth.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like this is a very broad question - which is out of scope for SO. While we are happy to help, it needs to be a _specific_ issue

Comment: I'll try to explain myself: I have an app (or a product, add-on... whatever you wanna call it) that actually connects to a person's twitter account and suggests him more pages\people to follow based on his search history\people followed etc. NOW - I want to add to that service the option to schedule tweets (I explained it on my first post..), for people to be able to manage it themselves. My question is: how do i add this functionality to my product? Like does it have to be made by some sort of code, or something else? I hope the question is a little more clear.. Thanks!

Comment: Can anyone help me with that please? Thanks!